# Add DataFrame columns located at subsequently increasing index values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Starting with an indexed DataFrame as follows:

```
            V_1
 13.823560  NaN
 13.823376  NaN
 13.823193  NaN
 13.823009  NaN
 ...        ...
 0.222725   NaN
 0.146151   NaN
 0.068280   NaN
-0.010880   NaN

[30000 rows x 1 columns]
```

The queries I have encountered so far only treat placement on column location values rather than on row location values.

How could I add 60 cols, each of length 500, from another DataFrame into the following (the remaining 29500 rows should become NaN's)?

Example of desired final DataFrame:

```
            V_1       V_2       V_3      ...    V_n
 13.823560  value1_1  NaN       NaN       ...    NaN
 13.823376  value1_2  NaN       NaN       ...    NaN
 13.823193  value1_3  NaN       NaN       ...    NaN
 13.823009  NaN       value2_1  NaN       ...    NaN
 13.822826  NaN       value2_2  NaN       ...    NaN
 13.822642  NaN       value2_3  NaN       ...    NaN
 13.822458  NaN       NaN       value3_1  ...    NaN
 13.822275  NaN       NaN       value3_2  ...    NaN
 13.822127  NaN       NaN       value3_3  ...    NaN
 ...        ...       ...       ...       ...    ...
 ...        ...       ...       ...       ...    ...
 0.222725   NaN       NaN       NaN       ...    NaN
 0.146151   NaN       NaN       NaN       ...    valueN_1
 0.068280   NaN       NaN       NaN       ...    valueN_2
-0.010880   NaN       NaN       NaN       ...    valueN_3
```

Where the 'value' elements are aligned exactly as in the DataFrame column these values were derived from.

If possible, it would be great to avoid element-wise allocation (due to time-optimization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some initial values:

```
numcols = 60
length = 500
n = 7
```

I can create a column of null values with:

```
df['V_'+str(n)] = np.repeat([np.nan], numcols*length)
```

Then I can use a range to fill it where I want:

```
df['V_'+str(n)].values[n*length:(n+1)*length] = some_values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a numpy array of NaN

```
>>> a = np.empty(500, dtype=<your data type>)
>>> a.fill(np.nan)
>>> a
array([ nan,  nan,  nan, ...])
```

Then fill your values

```
a[58:90] = myvalues
```

Then add it to the df

```
df.add(a)
```

This might be somewhat faster than iterating directly, although would be nice if someone can think of a way to create the numpy array in one go...